# Jenkins stash pull request builder plugin issue

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins stash pull request builder plugin to trigger the Jenkins build whenever a new pull request is opened. But it is triggering the build after some interval automatically. I am not able to find the root cause for the same. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a cron section which indicates interval to start looking for pull requests in stash. check if this interval is according to your need.